# Problem of dependency from OpenCMIS and other libs

Tags: java, maven, opencmis, websphere-9

in a project I am having a dependency problem that is driving me crazy.

We are talking about a Maven project, which has several modules

- WebModulo.war
- DAO.jar
- RESTModule.war
- EAR
- otherModule

REST services are implemented using javax rs.

In the DAO module I call a library that performs CRUDs on the Documentum repository through the OpenCMIS libraries. By importing only the library made by this colleague, at runtime when I invoke the service to download the file, this error returns me

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisContentAlreadyExistsException`

On another non maven project, I solved this error by adding cmis libraries in the ear:
`org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl:jar:1.1.0`

However, I tried to add cmis dependencies in the ear to my maven project, but to no avail.

After that I tried to add the dependencies in the DAO module, but at this point I get another error which I can't get out of
`Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/apache/neethi/AssertionBuilderFactory is not interface`

do you have any idea what the problem might be?

this is the dependency tree

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Module                                                          [pom]
[INFO] ModuleDAO                                                       [jar]
[INFO] ModuleBusiness                                                  [jar]
[INFO] TopolinoUtility                                                     [jar]
[INFO] ModuleREST                                                      [war]
[INFO] ModuleWeb                                                       [war]
[INFO] ModuleEAR                                                       [ear]
[INFO]

[INFO] -----------------------< it.micpia:ModuleDAO >------------------------
[INFO] Building ModuleDAO 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT                               [2/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:jar:1.1.0-MODIFICATA is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:jar:1.1.0-MODIFICATA is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ModuleDAO ---
[INFO] it.micpia:ModuleDAO:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-api:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings:jar:1.1.0-MODIFICATA:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |     +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-server-support:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |        \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
[INFO] +- it.micpia:DocumentumLib:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:micpia-security:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-sqlmap:jar:2.3.4.726:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:fixmicpia:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:intercon-utility-jca:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:accesso-at:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:isclioi:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:api-sicurezza:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] \- it.micpia.in.pf:session-utility:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- it.micpia.in.pf:cau-ws-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- it.micpia.in.pf:controlli-dto:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |        \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:jar:1.2.19:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO]


[INFO] -----------------------< it.micpia:ModuleREST >-----------------------
[INFO] Building ModuleREST 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT                              [5/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ModuleREST ---
[INFO] it.micpia:ModuleREST:war:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api:com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.json:jar:1.0.58:provided
[INFO] +- it.micpia:commonUtility:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:ModuleBusiness:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:ModuleDAO:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-api:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings:jar:1.1.0-MODIFICATA:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-server-support:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |        \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  \- it.micpia:DocumentumLib:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:TopolinoUtility:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl104-over-slf4j:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia.Module:proxyAuthSebServices:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia.Module:utilitaVarie:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:api-sicurezza:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:micpia-security:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-sqlmap:jar:2.3.4.726:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:fixmicpia:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:intercon-utility-jca:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:accesso-at:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:isclioi:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] \- it.micpia.in.pf:session-utility:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- it.micpia.in.pf:cau-ws-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- it.micpia.in.pf:controlli-dto:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO]

[INFO] -----------------------< it.micpia:ModuleEAR >------------------------
[INFO] Building ModuleEAR 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT                               [7/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ ear ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ModuleEAR ---
[INFO] it.micpia:ModuleEAR:ear:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- it.micpia:ModuleBusiness:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- it.micpia:commonUtility:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:ModuleDAO:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-api:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings:jar:1.1.0-MODIFICATA:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.0.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-server-support:jar:1.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |        \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  \- it.micpia:DocumentumLib:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:TopolinoUtility:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:ModuleWeb:war:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:ModuleREST:war:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:micpia-security:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-sqlmap:jar:2.3.4.726:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:fixmicpia:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:intercon-utility-jca:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:accesso-at:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.fin.in.ws.anag.spc:isclioi:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- it.micpia:api-sicurezza:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] \- it.micpia.in.pf:session-utility:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- it.micpia.in.pf:cau-ws-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- it.micpia.in.pf:controlli-dto:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |        \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:jar:1.2.19:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.6.2:compile
```